# $k^m$ where $k$ is infimum of $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} | m \le x^m\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

if $k = \inf\{x \in \mathbb{Q} | m \le x^m\}$ 
can I say that $k^m = m$?

Can you please explain why yes or why not?
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m=0$ this is wrong.

Then for $m\neq 0$ we have that $k=m^{\frac {1}{m}}$ even though that $k$ is irrational for $m\geq 2$ because of the density of rationals-irrationals in $\mathbb R$.

So for $m\neq 0 $ it is true.

Comment: could you please provide a better explanation for  $m \neq 0$?
Let's use a specific example where $m=7$

Comment: in the set $A=\{x\in \mathbb Q|7\leq x^7\}$ there is a sequence $(x_n)\in A$ such that $x_n\to k$ (from infimum characterization) because we assume that $A$ is low-bounded. Now,because $k=7^{\frac {1}{7}}$ is irrational,$k$ is not in $A$. This is not a problem because $k=7^{\frac {1}{7}}$ satisfies the equation and  is indeed the infimum because of the density of rationals in $\mathbb R$. This means that $x_n\to 7^{\frac {1}{7}}$